# Ruby : how to create a .downcase! style method?

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm learning Ruby, and I was wondering :
How to create a .downcase! style method ?
I could obviously make a method callable like downcase("CAPS LOCK")
But I want string.downcase.
Obviously that's an example, I know the downcase method exists.
How do you do that ?
Thanks !

Comment: Why not just do `your_string.downcase!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a method, it is available and called in the context of an object. That means every method call has an implicit scope. `downcase` really means `self.downcase`.

For example if you define a method directly, it's added as a private method on the `main` context for the script.

```
self
# => main

def downcase
end

# private_methods means self.private_methods

private_methods.include?(:downcase)
# => true
```

If you want an object instance to call a method in it's context, define the method on the class.

```
class String
  def my_downcase
  end
end

"string".methods.include?(:my_downcase)
# => true

"string".my_downcase
```

Adding methods to built-in types is called *monkey-patching* and it's sort of frowned upon. Better to subclass the object to add functionality. The String constructor takes a string which is great for subclassing, and **[String#replace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-replace)** works for modifying the string in-place.

```
class CoolString < String
  def initialize(str)
    super(str)
  end

  def downcase!
    replace(downcase)
  end
end

str = CoolString.new("STRING")
str.downcase!
str
# => "string"
```

Comment: Thank you guys a lots for the explanations.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend core classes easily:

```
class String
  def make_it_downcase!
    replace downcase   # Calls downcase on the current value and replaces it with the result. 
  end
end
```

See it in action:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0>     class String
irb(main):002:1>       def make_it_downcase!
irb(main):003:2>         replace downcase
irb(main):004:2>       end
irb(main):005:1>     end
=> :make_it_downcase!
irb(main):006:0> test = "TEST"
=> "TEST"
irb(main):007:0> test.make_it_downcase!
=> "test"
irb(main):008:0> test
=> "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the string class like so:

```
class String
  def downcase
     #implementation
  end
end
```